# C#: Open webbrowser within task --> currently STA problem

Tags: c#, wpf, task, mahapps.metro

**General:**

1. WPF application
2. Using mahapps.metro
3. Using mahapps progress dialog

**What do I want to achieve**

1. Open mahapps progress dialog
2. During progress dialog doing some stuff
3. One of the doing stuff is to open a webbrowser element for user login --> after login I get the cookies back
4. Do some stuff only after login procedure (task)

**Current Problem**

The problem is, that I have to create a task for the mahapps progress dialog like the following ...

```
public async void startWork(view)
    {
        MahApps.Metro.Controls.MetroWindow window = Window.GetWindow(view) as MahApps.Metro.Controls.MetroWindow;
         if (window != null)
         {
             var controller = await window.ShowProgressAsync("Please wait...", "Progress message");
             controller.Maximum = 100;

             await Task.Run(() => {

                  Login.RunAuthentification(controller, IDApp, IDToken, BaseUrl);
             });
            await controller.CloseAsync();
         }}
```

Within **RunAuthentification** I have a function for the webbrowser, looking like this

```
public static async Task<string> openLogin(string _authorizationUrl)
    {
        string sessionId = null;

        if (_authorizationUrl.Length == 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Authorization url cannot be empty");
        }

        // The method should return based on an event.
        // We need a Semaphore which we can then be released in the event handler
        var signal = new System.Threading.SemaphoreSlim(0, 1);


        // Create a WindowsForms window
        var window = new System.Windows.Forms.Form
        {
            Text = "Please provide your login ...",
            Size = new System.Drawing.Size(800, 545)
        };

        // Create a WindowsForms WebBrowser element
        var browser = new System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser
        {
            Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
            Url = new Uri(_authorizationUrl)
        };
        // Add the browser to the window
        window.Controls.Add(browser);

        // If the window is closed, release the signal so the async task will be completed
        window.Closed += (sender, args) => signal.Release();

        // We will listen for any change of the url and wait for the authorization code.
        // The browser might be redirected multiple times

        browser.DocumentCompleted += (sender, eventArgs) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine(eventArgs.Url.ToString());

            if (eventArgs.Url.AbsolutePath.EndsWith("/confirmed"))
            {
                var cookies = browser.Document?.Cookie.Split(';')
                    .Select(keyValueStr => keyValueStr.Split('='))
                    .ToDictionary(arr => arr[0].Trim(), arr => arr[1].Trim());

                cookies?.TryGetValue("SESSION", out sessionId);
                window.Close();
            }
        };

        // Show the window
        window.ShowDialog();

        // Wait until the signal is set
        await signal.WaitAsync();
        return sessionId;
    }
```

Now I get the error message that I cannot access the webbrowser because the actual thread isnt a STA. Does anyone have an idea how I can solve this elegantly?

Comment: Can you show the stacktrace of the exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to make use of either the Dispatcher or the DispatcherSynchronizationContext to "marshal" the call from within your Task to the main UI thread. Here's how you could use the DispatcherSynchronizationContext:

```
public async void startWork(view)
{
    MahApps.Metro.Controls.MetroWindow window = Window.GetWindow(view) as MahApps.Metro.Controls.MetroWindow;
    if (window != null)
    {
        var controller = await window.ShowProgressAsync("Please wait...", "Progress message");
        controller.Maximum = 100;
         
        //capture the current SynchronizationContext
        var context = SynchronizationContext.Current;

        await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(() =>
        {
            //use the context to marshal the call on the main UI thread
            context.Send((o) => Login.RunAuthentification(controller, IDApp, IDToken, BaseUrl), null);
        });

        await controller.CloseAsync();
     }
}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.threading.dispatchersynchronizationcontext?redirectedfrom=MSDN

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.threading.dispatcher

Comment: Sorry for my late answer. If I use your solution I get the "error" message that a method name was expected (CS0149)?

Comment: Corrected. That's what I get for coding without Visual Studio and Intellisense.